# problem with sending and displaying info about validation results

Tags: php, html

I have user registration form that calls another file which calls an object that performs validation.

I would like to create this form to be sticky and display info about validation errors next to respective fields.

How can I resend data to the page with the form?

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You could use client-side JavaScript validation (and back that up with server-side PHP validation too) but if you set the forms' POST target to be the same page that generates the form (so $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) you could call the validation object/class in a statement like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Validation code
}

// Generate form along with any output from validation script
```